# GridLayout Representing an ArrayList of JLabels issue

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm looking for a bit of help with a problem I'm having. I am creating a GridLayout on my GUI and in each Grid there will be a JLabel. Along side this I have an ArrayList which contains images which will be displayed in each Grid.

What I am trying to do is when I click a specific grid, it will add an image from the ArrayList and place it in the grid position. What I would like is have a left click to add the item in the ArrayList and a right click to remove the item in the list.

The ArrayList and GUI code are in different classes and the ArrayList is implemented in the main method. I have tried to no avail, I cannot seem to get the grids to represent the list.

Basically I need a GridLayout to give a visual representation of an ArrayList, that can be manipulated with mouse interaction

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Code for the Grids:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) 
    {
        JLabel assetLabel = new JLabel("Test"+(i+1));

        System.out.println("assetLabel"+(i));

        assetLabel.addMouseListener(new ParcelInfo(i));

        assetLabel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        assetLabel.setOpaque(true);
        assetGrid.add(assetLabel);
    }
```

Code for the items I need in the JLabel:

```
public class test 
{
    private ImageIcon img;

    test(ImageIcon i)
    {
        this.img=i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ive edited to show to GridLayout.  It displays the grids perfectly, what im having a problem with though is getting my ArrayList of images to be manipulated on which grid is in question.

Comment: `JList` or `JTable`...

Answer (score 0):

This is how you define a Listener for it.

```
public List<Image> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
public OtherClassWithArray foo = new OtherClassWithArray();

jLabel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            if(e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) // left click
            jLabel.setIcon(arrayList.get(xyz)); // access arraylist here
            // jLabel.setIcon(foo.getArrayList.get(xyz); // access arrayList from other class
            else // right click
            // do smth here
        }
    });
```

Comment: So each of the JLabels in the grid would each have a listener?  And then within the class that contains the ImageIcon have that grab the relevant ArrayList icon?

Comment: @BeanShares Yes, this is one way to do it.

Comment: Cool, il try and implement this. The only thing i can think that will not work is that my ArrayList is created in the main method and if i called another version of the ArrayList wouldn't it be empty?  How could i pass in the current ArrayList through as a parameter?

Comment: @BeanShares You can't pass it as a parameter. But you can access it, look my edit.

Comment: If i called a new ArrayList,  i would lost my current list though?  Is there no way i can use my current ArrayList used in another class?

Comment: Thanks so much, il go and give it ago now. Hopefully this will get me going again!   Appreciate all the help thanks.